# How to remove list item using button on said list item

Tags: javascript, removechild

Im building a todo list and Im having trouble figuring out the remove function. I keep getting an error that states "Node not found".

I was coding most a lot of this on my own but I looked up a tutorial for this part. They suggested using:

```
function removeItem() {
var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
var parent = this.parentNode;
parent.removeChild(item);
};
```

I tried to apply it to the code i already had but it doesn't seem to work. 
also im not entirely clear on the logic of:

```
var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
var parent = this.parentNode;
```

If someone could also explain what this does also that would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/styles.css">
  </head>
<body>

<header id="addtodo">

  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add an item"/>
  <button id="button"  type="button">Add item</button>
</header>

  <div id="listcontainer">
    <ul id="itemlist">

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="dividerline">

  </div>

  <div id="completecontainer">
    <ul id="completed">

    </ul>
  </div>



    <script src="resources/JS/code.js"></script>
  </body>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
var value = document.getElementById('input').value;

var item = document.createElement("li");

var itemText = document.createTextNode(value);

var itemdiv= document.createElement('div');
var buttons=document.createElement('div');
var text=document.createElement('div');

var remove = document.createElement("button");
var complete = document.createElement("button");
var itemlist = document.getElementById('itemlist');




item.appendChild(itemdiv);
itemdiv.appendChild(text);
text.appendChild(itemText);
itemdiv.appendChild(buttons);
buttons.appendChild(complete);
buttons.appendChild(remove);

remove.innerHTML = 'Remove';
complete.innerHTML = 'Complete';

remove.classList.add('remove');
remove.setAttribute('id','remove');

complete.classList.add('complete');
complete.setAttribute('id','complete');

buttons.classList.add('buttondiv');
text.classList.add('text');
itemdiv.classList.add('itemdiv');

remove.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
complete.addEventListener('click', completeItem);

itemlist.insertBefore(item, itemlist.childNodes[0]);
});


function removeItem() {
var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
var parent = this.parentNode;
parent.removeChild(item);
};

function completeItem() {
var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
var parent = this.parentNode;
parent.removeChild(item);
};
```

I want the remove button to remove the list item its attached to.

Comment: Did you mean `item.removeChild(parent)`?

Comment: Also, you don't need to do that at all. Just call `.remove()` on the item you want to remove from the DOM.

Comment: **ID must be unique** your code duplicate them on your buttons remove and complete. and this is very bad!

Comment: you should have a look at my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first, use `console.log()` function to debug your code:

```
  function removeItem() {
    var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    var parent = this.parentNode;
    console.log( 'item', item ); // => <div class="itemdiv">
    console.log( 'parent', parent ); // => <div class="buttondiv">
    parent.removeChild(item);
  };
```

As you can see:
1) You mixed up item and parent nodes.
2) If you want to delete a whole `<li>` element, you have to use more `parentNode`:

```
function removeItem() {
  var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  var item = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  console.log( 'item', item ); // => <li>
  console.log( 'parent', parent ); // => <ul id="itemlist">
  parent.removeChild(item);
};
```

Or call `remove()` method right on your item:

```
function removeItem() {
  var item = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  item.remove();
};
```

But the best way be using `closest()` method:

```
function removeItem() {
  var item = this.closest( 'li' );
  item.remove();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the function

```
function completeItem() {
  var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  var parent = this.parentNode;
  parent.removeChild(item);
};
```

Swap the `item` and `parent`, like so: `parent.removeChild(item);`

Answer (score 1):

For this case arrows functions are the most easiest way : (and clone node too)

```js
const myButton       = document.getElementById('my-button')
    , textInput      = document.getElementById('text-input')
    , ListItems      = document.getElementById('itemlist')
    , LI_clone4Items = document.querySelector('#clone4Items > li')

var count = 0

myButton.onclick=_=>
{
  let newLI = LI_clone4Items.cloneNode(true)
  ListItems.insertBefore(newLI, ListItems.childNodes[0])
  newLI.querySelector('.text').textContent = textInput.value
  newLI.querySelector('.complete').onclick =_=> { ListItems.removeChild(newLI) }
  newLI.querySelector('.remove').onclick   =_=> { ListItems.removeChild(newLI) }
  textInput.value = ''
  myButton.disabled = true
}

(textInputControl =_=> { myButton.disabled = (textInput.value.trim()==='') })()

textInput.oninput = textInputControl
```

```html
<header id="addtodo">
  <input type="text" id="text-input" placeholder="Add an item" />
  <button id="my-button" type="button">Add item</button>
</header>

<div id="listcontainer">
  <ul id="itemlist"></ul>
</div>

<div id="dividerline">
</div>

<div id="completecontainer">
  <ul id="completed"></ul>
</div>

<!-- hidden -->
<div style="display:none">
  <ul id="clone4Items">
    <li>
      <div class="itemdiv">
        <div class="text"></div>
        <div class="buttondiv">
          <button class="complete" >Complete</button>
          <button class="remove" >Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to forget `parentNode` and just give the new `<li>` a unique class. Then, you can remove the `<li>` with the [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method.

Also, you are creating some unnecessary nodes and should really name the variables more descriptively.

Additionally, you can't have multiple elements with the same `id` and frankly, you don't need the new elements to have `id`s in the first place, so forget that.

Lastly, do all the creation and configuration of a new element before moving on to the next one. It makes the code more simple to read and prevents you from forgetting to configure things.

```js
var list = document.getElementById("itemlist");
var todo = document.getElementById('input');

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(){

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = todo.value;
  li.classList.add("container");

  var itemDiv= document.createElement('div');
  var buttonDiv=document.createElement('div');

  var removeBtn = document.createElement("button");
  removeBtn.textContent = 'Remove';
  removeBtn.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
  removeBtn.classList.add('remove');
  
  var completeBtn = document.createElement("button");
  completeBtn.textContent = 'Complete';
  completeBtn.addEventListener('click', completeItem);
  completeBtn.classList.add('complete');

  // Append your items from the inside out
  buttonDiv.appendChild(completeBtn);
  buttonDiv.appendChild(removeBtn);
  itemDiv.appendChild(buttonDiv);
  li.appendChild(itemDiv);

  list.insertBefore(li, list.childNodes[0]);
});


function removeItem() {
  //Just find the closese ancestor that matches the selector and remove it
  this.closest(".container").remove();
};

function completeItem() {
var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
var parent = this.parentNode;
parent.removeChild(item);
};
```

```html
<header id="addtodo">

  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add an item"/>
  <button id="button"  type="button">Add item</button>
</header>

  <div id="listcontainer">
    <ul id="itemlist">

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="dividerline">

  </div>

  <div id="completecontainer">
    <ul id="completed">

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are trying to capture the list item from the parent function. `this.parentNode.parentNode` grabs the div item that the button is in. call `item.parentNode` to get the outer list-item object and instead of removing the item from the parent just remove the whole list-item

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(e){
 var value = document.getElementById('input').value;

 var item = document.createElement("li");

  var itemText = document.createTextNode(value);

  var itemdiv= document.createElement('div');
  var buttons=document.createElement('div');
  var text=document.createElement('div');

  var remove = document.createElement("button");
  var complete = document.createElement("button");
  var itemlist = document.getElementById('itemlist');

  item.appendChild(itemdiv);
  itemdiv.appendChild(text);
  text.appendChild(itemText);
  itemdiv.appendChild(buttons);
  buttons.appendChild(complete);
  buttons.appendChild(remove);

  remove.innerHTML = 'Remove';
  complete.innerHTML = 'Complete';

  remove.classList.add('remove');
  remove.setAttribute('id','remove');

  complete.classList.add('complete');
  complete.setAttribute('id','complete');

  buttons.classList.add('buttondiv');
  text.classList.add('text');
  itemdiv.classList.add('itemdiv');

  remove.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
  complete.addEventListener('click', completeItem);

  itemlist.insertBefore(item, itemlist.childNodes[0]);
});


function removeItem() {
  var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  var parent = item.parentNode;
  parent.remove()
};

function completeItem() {
  var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  var parent = item.parentNode;
  
  parent.remove()
};
```

```html
<header id="addtodo">

  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add an item"/>
  <button id="button"  type="button">Add item</button>
</header>

  <div id="listcontainer">
    <ul id="itemlist">

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="dividerline">

  </div>

  <div id="completecontainer">
    <ul id="completed">

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please don't post code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just include a code snippet right here in your answer.